# how populate a Partial View on page load using ajax in asp.net mvc with some query?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, model

I'm working on `Asp.net MVC 5` project . I have below code and it works fine without error , my problem is : in page load showed all of records  , I want to show a specific record . How can I do it ?

controller :

```
public ActionResult GoodDetails(int id)
    {
        HomeVM vm = new HomeVM();
        var goodDetails = db.GoodDetails.Where(p => p.FKSubGoods == id).ToList();
        vm.GoodDetails = goodDetails;
        return View(vm);

    }
public PartialViewResult GoodDetailsAjax(int id)
    {
        HomeVM vm = new HomeVM();
        var GoodDetailsAjax = db.GoodDetails.Where(p => p.DetailsGoodID == id).ToList();
        vm.GoodDetails = GoodDetailsAjax;
        return PartialView("_GoodDetailsAjax", vm);
    }
```

_GoodDetailsAjax.cshtml :

```
 @model NP1.ViewModels.HomeVM
 <div>
    @foreach (var item in Model.GoodDetails)
    {
    <img class="img-responsive" src="@Url.Content(item.DetailsImage1.ToString())">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="@Url.Content(item.DetailsImage2.ToString())">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="@Url.Content(item.DetailsImage3.ToString())">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="@Url.Content(item.DetailsImage3.ToString())">

}
</div>
```

I added `@{Html.RenderPartial("_GoodDetailsAjax", Model);}` to `Target div` to show a record on page load , but it shows all records and I don't know how write a specific record. I wrote some codes instead of `Model` but they didn't work .
Thanks for any help .

```
<div>
@foreach (var item1 in Model.GoodDetails)
{
    @Ajax.ActionLink("LinkText", "GoodDetailsAjax", new { id = @item1.DetailsGoodID }, new AjaxOptions()
{
HttpMethod = "GET",
UpdateTargetId = "DivAjax",
InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
}
)
      <input type="image" src="@Url.Content(item1.DetailsSmallImage1.ToString())">


}
</div>

 <div id="DivAjax">
     @{Html.RenderPartial("_GoodDetailsAjax", Model);}
 </div>
```

Comment: Which specific record? You need to use `@{ Html.RenderAction("GoodDetailsAjax", new { id = someValue }); }` to call the method and pass it the `ID` you want to display.

Comment: Thank you , I use `@{ Html.RenderAction("GoodDetailsAjax", new { id = 5 }); }` and it works and show a record with `5 id` .  for example in parent `view` I have `Home/GoodDetails/3` , and I have 2 (child) records with id 3 . I want show one of this child . @Stephen Muecke

Comment: Its not clear what your asking. And why does `GoodDetailsAjax` return `HomeVM` when all you seem to be displaying is the `GoodDetails` property? (the model in the partial should just be `IEnumerable<GoodDetails>`.

Comment: sorry , my English is very bad and I don't know how explain my problem :(  . When I go to `http://localhost:35676/Home/GoodDetails/3` ,  2 records showed : `record1= fk=3,ID=5 and record2=fk=3,ID=6` . each of these records have some other fields , I want in page load one of `ID=5` or `ID=6` with it's fields  showed .what changes need in  `@{ Html.RenderAction("GoodDetailsAjax", new { id = 5 }); }` . sorry for get your time

Comment: @shimaamini you are returning List<GoodDetail> from `GoodDetailsAjax` action. If you want to first record then return only the first record or of a specific record then add the business logic to return only 1 of the record. Agreed with @StephenMuecke that partial view should we change to `GoodDetail` model if you want to use it only 1 record at a time or `IEnumerable<GoodDetail>` if more than 1.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by _one of `ID=5` or `ID=6`_. You can use `@{ Html.RenderAction("GoodDetailsAjax", new { id = Model.FirstOrDefault().DetailsGoodID }); }` if you want to return the first one

Comment: I changed the Model to `GoodDetailVM` and `IEnumerable<GoodDetail>` and `IList<GoodDetail>` but gave me error . Thank you dear @user1672994 I need some time to learn these subjects you said .

Comment: Thank you very much @StephenMuecke , That's exactlly what I want. `@{ Html.RenderAction("GoodDetailsAjax", new { id = Model.FirstOrDefault().DetailsGoodID }); }`  works fine :)

Comment: Note that `FirstOrDefault()` will return `null` if there are no items in the collection in which case it would throw an exception because you cannot access the `DetailsGoodID` property of `null`. You should add a `if (Model.Any()) {...` check first

Comment: Can I put this long query in `Html.RenderAction` ? It seems gave me error :/

Comment: @shimaamini (note how this message starts if you want to notify someone). No, the `RenderAction()` needs to be inside the `if` block

Comment: OK , Thank you again dear @StephenMuecke